# Call async method in new task c#

Tags: c#, async-await, task, tpl-dataflow

Problem i'm trying to solve:

For each directory, it exists some files, and I want to upload this to Azure.

So I want to do this:
Task1 - uploading files in directory 1 to azure
Task 2 - uploading files in directory 2 to azure

I want to do this concurrently.

I have the following code:

```
private async Task ProcessMatFiles(string directory, List<FileInfo> matFiles)
{
    foreach (var file in matFiles)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.Name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(directory) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FullName))
        {
            var cloudBlockBlob = this._cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("textures/" + directory + "/" + file.Name);

            if (!await cloudBlockBlob.ExistsAsync())
                await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(file.FullName);
        }
    }
```

```cs
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var directory in matFileDirectories)
{
    // Get all the files in the directory
    var matFiles = new DirectoryInfo(directory).EnumerateFiles().ToList();

    // Get the directory name of the files
    var matDirectory = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(matFiles.FirstOrDefault().FullName));

    if (matFiles.Count > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(matDirectory))
    {
        var task = new Task(() =>this.ProcessMatFiles(matDirectory, matFiles));
        tasks.Add(task);
        task.Start();
    }
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

With this code, i get the following warning:

> Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method
>   continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await'
>   operator to the result of the call.

What does that mean? How does this affect my code?

I can remove the warning by doing like this:

```cs
var task = new Task(async () => await this.ProcessMatFiles());
```

Is this the correct way to this?

Comment: No, don't use `Task.Start()` and `Task.Wait()`. That defeats the purpose of tasks. They aren't threads, they are a *promise* that something will produce a result in the future. Use `Task.Run` or `await`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos check my updated question. Im creating many tasks and then wait for them to complete.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how would you do instead in my case?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `await`? Every edit adds extra problems. `Task.Wait()` won't wait on the async process it will await on the task that starts that async process. The result is still a fire-and-forget call with an extra `Task` object for the GC to collect. You could have just written `ProcessMatFiles`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you give me an example how you would do it?

Comment: Do *what*? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Process one file at a time without blocking? Simply use `await ProcessMatFiles(matDirectory, matFiles);`. Start processing all files in parallel? Put the `Task` already returned by `ProcessMatFiles` in the list and await all those tasks at the end with `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`. You can even convert the loop into a LINQ query whose final step is a `select.ProcessMatFiles(matDirectory, matFiles)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated my question with my problem im trying to solve.

Comment: @Bryan in that case you need to process the files one by one. Each upload is a separate asynchronous operation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i also provided the code for ProcessMatFiles. I just want to upload the files for the different directories independent of each other.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos awesome. Brillaint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *real* problem seems to be how to process multiple files in parallel. `ProcessMatFiles` returns a `Task` already and I'd assume it doesn't run anything heavy on the caller's thread. That task can be stored in the `tasks` list. That list can be awaited without blocking with

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

A better solution would be to convert the entire loop into a LINQ query that returns the Tasks and await it.

```
var tasks = from var directory in matFileDirectories
            let dir=new DirectoryInfo(directory)
            let files=dir.GetFiles()
            select ProcessMatFiles(dir.Name, files));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

The problem with this is that enumerating the files in a folder is expensive itself, and `GetFiles()`, or using `EnumerateFiles().ToList()` has to wait for the enumeration to finish. It would be better if `ProcessMatFiles` received the DirectoryInfo object and enumerated the files *in a separate thread*.

Another improvement would be to process the files one-by-one :

```
var tasks = from var directory in matFileDirectories
            let dir=new DirectoryInfo(directory)
            from file in dir.EnumerateFiles()
            select ProcessMatFile(dir.Name, file));
```

It's possible to improve this further if one knows what `ProcessMatFiles` does, eg use Dataflow blocks or Channels for throttling and using a specific number of tasks, breaking the process into multiple concurrent steps etc.

**Update**

Since this is a file upload operation, each file is a separate asynchronous operation. Most of the checks can be removed when working with DirectoryInfo and FileInfo objects.

The upload method should be just :

```
async Task Upload(FileInfo file)
{
    var folder=file.Directory.Name;
    var blob = _cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(${"textures/{folder}/{file.Name}";
    if (!await blob.ExistsAsync())
    {
        await blob.UploadFromFileAsync(file.FullName);
    }
}
```

The task-producing query can be simplified to :

```
var tasks = from var directory in matFileDirectories
            let dir=new DirectoryInfo(directory)
            from file in dir.EnumerateFiles()
            select UploadFile(file);

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This will try to fire off all upload operations as fast as the files can be iterated. This could flood the network. One solution is to use an [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=netcore-3.0) that will only use eg 8 tasks at a time to upload files. A limit is placed on the input buffer too, to avoid filling it with eg 1000 FileInfo items :

```
var options=new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
      {
         MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8,  //Only 8 concurrent operations
         BoundedCapacity=64           //Block posters if the input buffer has too many items
      } ;
var block=new ActionBlock<FileInfo>(async file=>UploadFile(file),options);

var files = from var directory in matFileDirectories
            let dir=new DirectoryInfo(directory)
            from file in dir.EnumerateFiles()
            select file;

foreach(var file in files)
{
    //Wait here if the input buffer is full
    await block.SendAsync(file);
}

block.Complete();

//Wait for all uploads to finish
await block.Completion;
```